# How to upload attachments to Yammer using rest api in php

Tags: yammer

How to upload attachments to Yammer using rest api in php. Can anyone give one example. I have tried long and hard but I am not able to post any attachments. But using https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json this in POST I am easily able to post my messages and OG objects.

I think the documentation in yammer is not enough to implement this. So any example code in php would be great.

Comment: Hi..I need help to implement the same task. Can you help me..